# How to activate User-Defined cost allocation tags using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any way to **activate** the **User Defined cost allocation tags** using **boto3** API instead of 'AWS Cost Allocation Tags' console?

Verified the Cost Explorer section in boto3 but didn't find any API which will provide this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yeah doesn't even look like there is any cli methods to activate the tags. the only methods outside of the console look to be simply setting the allocation tags on specific resources...but you have to use each individual resource api to do the tagging.
[enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/custom-tags.html)

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI now have it. See [update/activate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/update-cost-allocation-tags-status.html) and [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/list-cost-allocation-tags.html) actions

boto3 has the same. See [update_cost_allocation_tags_status](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.update_cost_allocation_tags_status)

AWS CLI example:

TAGKEY='aws:createdBy'

aws ce update-cost-allocation-tags-status --cost-allocation-tags-status="TagKey=${TAGKEY},Status=Active"